# How to set text using TextEditingController and placing the cursor at the end?

Tags: flutter

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: TextField(
      controller: _controller,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      onChanged: (string) {
        _controller.text = string; // Removing this works though!
        _controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: _controller.text.length));
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

**Problem:**

[image]

As you can clearly see in the screenshot about the problem, typing `12` prints `21` and so on. You might ask what's the use of setting text in `TextEditingController` to the current string passed by `onChanged`, well, I need to format the current string but even the simplest string isn't able to set the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can do the magic for you!

```
onChanged: (newText) {
    var text = formatString(newText);
    _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(
       text: text,
       selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: text.length),
   );
}
```

Do your formatting like this and don't forget every time the newText is passed with already formatted value. 
 (In this case, I replaced all commas to bring back my original string)

```
  String formatString(String newText){
    return newText.replaceAll(',', '').split('').join(',');
  }
```

Interactive Example Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html#widgets.TextEditingController.1

Comment: Thanks, but that example can easily be done by using `string.toLowerCase()` in my code. Problem comes when I need to insert commas in the formatted string.

Comment: Is it possible to insert commas when we use TextInputType.number?

Comment: You can consider an example when user types a number say a million: 1,000,000.